# option menu not working with Webview?

Tags: android, webview

i am using webview in activity and want to use option menu too.
but it does not display option menu on clicking menu button any one guide me what could be the problem?

```
oncreate
{

 _webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                //if(_dialog != null && !_dialog.isShowing())
                //  _dialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                 if (_dialog != null && _dialog.isShowing()) {
                     _dialog.dismiss();
                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                if (Constants.LOG)
                    Log.d("recieved error", "");
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                try {
                     if (_dialog != null && _dialog.isShowing())
                    _dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }


        });



        _webView.loadUrl(Constants.URL_VOLUNTEER);

}
```

menu

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            menu.add(0, 0, 0, Constants.MENU_ITEM_HOME);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 0:
                Intent intentHomeScreen= new Intent(this,HomeScreen.class);
                intentHomeScreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intentHomeScreen);
                break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            if(_dialog != null)
                _dialog.dismiss();
            if(_webView != null)
            _webView.stopLoading();
            this.finish();

        }

        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing with `WebView` that interferes with options menus, AFAIK. I have created activities with a `WebView` and an options menu before, though not in around nine months. Remove the `WebView` temporarily -- if the options menu still misbehaves, then you have some other issue, such as a malformed `onKeyDown()` implementation.

Comment: yes i have implemented onkeydown event please check my post i have edited it. and let me know whats wrong with it?

Comment: @UMAR: Only return `true` from within your `if()` block. Return `super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)` for any button you are *not* handling.